# Compiler Unaware of Provided Methods of Trait

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, prost

I'm using the `prost` crate in a very "hello world" way, with a basic ProtoBuf file:

### foo.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package foo;

message Foo {
    string mystring = 1;
}
```

I can verify the types that prost produces at compile time by inspecting `./target/PROJECT/build/PROJECT-{some hash}/out/foo.rs`:

### foo.rs

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, ::prost::Message)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[prost(string, tag="1")]
    pub mystring: ::prost::alloc::string::String,
}
```

See that the `prost::Message` trait gets derived? [Its docs](https://docs.rs/prost/latest/prost/trait.Message.html) claim I have tons of functions at my disposal for this trait, but only the two required ones, `encoded_len()` and `clear()`, can be called without error. Any of the provided ones (those with default implementations) result in a `cannot find function in this scope` error.

### main.rs

```
use prost::Message;

pub mod foo {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/foo.rs"));
}

fn main() {
    let f = foo::Foo { mystring: "bar".to_string() };
    let v = encode_to_vec(&f);
}
```

`cargo run`

> ```
> error[E0425]: cannot find function `encode_to_vec` in this scope
>    |
>    |     let v = encode_to_vec(&f);
>    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
> ```

And, worryingly, this warning implies it's not even looking at the trait it needs to:

> warning: unused import: `prost::Message`

(edit) For reference:

### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "testing"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
prost = { version = "0.7.0", features = ["std"] }

[build-dependencies]
prost-build = "0.7.0"
```

Comment: Extra info: My Cargo.toml depends on `prost` using `features=["std"]`, and I ensured the Foo struct implements the `Sized` trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encode_to_vec` is not a free function. You need to call it as one of

- `f.encode_to_vec()`
- `foo::Foo::encode_to_vec(&f)`
- `Message::encode_to_vec(&f)`
- `<foo::Foo as Message>::encode_to_vec(&f)`

The first method is the most normal, but the other ones may produce useful error messages when you get confused about what's going on.

---

[Edit:] Well, `encode_to_vec` was added in prost [0.8.0](https://docs.rs/prost/0.8.0/prost/trait.Message.html#method.encode_to_vec), so with [0.7.0](https://docs.rs/prost/0.8.0/prost/trait.Message.html#method.encode_to_vec), it won't be usable.

Comment: Nope, all 4 of those ways produce errors. Either `cannot find method or associated constant 'encode_to_vec' in trait 'Message'` or `function or associated item not found in 'Foo'`

Comment: Can't reproduce. What prost version are you using? (Maybe edit your question and add the entire `Cargo.toml`…)

Comment: Edited answer to include `Cargo.toml` but this was the problem - I was only on v. 0.7.0. Updating to 0.9.0 solved this.